# R: adding horizontal lines to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am using the ggplot2 library in R.

Suppose I have a graph that looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(work) + geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = var2, group = 1)) +
               theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
               ggtitle("sample graph")
```

Is there a way to directly add a second line to this graph?

e.g.

```
ggplot(work) + geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = var2, group = 1)) +
               geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = mean(var2), group = 1)) +
               theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
               ggtitle("Sample graph")
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: A few typos in your code : forgotten `)` - it seems to work with edits above. As suggested by @Ronak Shah, please supply MRE if it still doesn't work as you'd like

Comment: `geom_hline(yintercept = mean(var2))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed it is possible:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
        geom_line(aes(y = hp), col = "red") +
        geom_line(aes(y = mean(hp)), col = "blue")
```

[image]

However, for specifically horizontal lines, I would use `geom_hline` intstead:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
        geom_line(col = "blue") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mtcars$hp), col = "red")
```

[image]